# Java Servlet execute method before serving page

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I want to be able to have a method between getting the HTTP request and sending the webpage. A close equivalent to what I want is having some code on top of every jsp file.

Example:

```
<%
    some.package.staticMethod();
%>
```

Does this make sense?

I believe ASP.net has a method Page_Load similar to what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is applicable to all the responses for incoming HTTP requests, then you are talking about a [Servlet Filter](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-06-2001/jw-0622-filters.html).